# What is the plural of "detective sergeant"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

What is the plural of "detective sergeant". In an episode of *[Endeavour](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=endeavour-2013&episode=s05e04)*, Series 5, episode 4, Superintendent Bright used "detectives sergeant" but this seems wrong, you wouldn't say "chiefs inspector" would you?

> Chief Superintendent Bright, Thames Valley, **Detectives Sergeant** Strange and Morse, and Detective Constable Fancy.

Answer (score 9):

The origin of the noun *detective*, as in a policeman who 'detects' crimes, is the adjective:

> 1828, short for *detective police*, from *detective* (adj.) "fitted for or skilled in detecting" (by 1828);
>   — *Etymonline*

It follows that, in *detective sergeant*, the word should also really be an adjective. That means the head of the noun group is *sergeant*, and *detective* is a simple attribute. Only the head should be pluralised, so it should be *detective sergeants*.

The script writers may have been confused by words like *Knight Templar*, in which the first word can be read as the noun and the second the adjective, in which case it should be *Knights Templar*.

Comment: Because of potential confusion with ***Queen's regent*** (singular "regent of The Queen"), a better example might be ***Knights Templar***. And personally I don't really care much about the (inaudible) hyphen in ***Presidents-elect***. Whatever - those scriptwriters really should learn better English, in a job like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Very well, I'll replace it.

Comment: I have a feeling it's a hypercorrection from the rule in titles such as attorneys-general, governors-general, sergeants major, maybe even stuff like passers-by or courts martial. Also, @Jonno I have a doubt someone would be able to hear the difference between "detectives sergeant" and "detective sergeant".  You would have to leave a strangely long pause between the two words to be able to distinguish the two esses.

Comment: @Zebrafish: Yes, what I was trying to say in my last paragraph.

Comment: Plurals of compound words are highly ideosyncratic, they don't follow any general rules.

Comment: Superintendent Bright is deliberately using the wrong plural as a kind of self-parody. The script writers knew exactly what they were doing.

Comment: Yes, "detective", as used by police forces, is an adjective - but one which is often given informal noun status in references  such as "there are three detectives attached to the station".  But each of those "detectives" has a full handle. Each will be either a "detective constable", "detective sergeant", "detective inspector", detective superintendent", or possibly "detective chief-superintendent". In all those cases "detective" is adjectival, though each, in shorthand can be described as "a detective".

Comment: @FumbleFingers why blame the scriptwriters. Maybe it was the actor's fault? How audible is the error in any case?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I was assuming he read the script, or it wouldn't have been audible.

Comment: @TonyK: You might want to post that as an answer!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think TonyK is correct, this was almost certainly an intentional error. I haven't watched the series, but knowing it's a prequel of the Inspector Morse stories which often played on the stereotype of the uneducated policeman vs well-educated / upper class academics (with Morse himself having one foot in each world), this is exactly the kind of wordplay that you would expect to find in it.